# Receiving TaskCanceledException when making http request

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task, httpclient

I received `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` when making Http request.

```
public async Task<CommonResult<T>> GetRequest<T>(TokenModel token, string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.TokenType, token.AccessToken);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await OK<T>(response);
        }
        else
        {
            //The response is authorized but some other error.
            if (IsAuthorized(response.StatusCode))
                return Error<T>(response.StatusCode.ToString());

            //Unable to refresh token.
            if (!await RenewToken(token))
                return Error<T>("Fail to refresh token");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(GlobalData.Token.TokenType, GlobalData.Token.AccessToken);
            response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await OK<T>(response);
            }
            else
            {
                return Error<T>(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It happens when I debug the server code and not continue. Is this natural behaviour or am I missing something in the client code?

Comment: is there an InnerException?

Comment: No is null. The message say 'A task was cancelled'

Comment: You're likely hitting HTTP timeout. What you're calling? Does it work manually, e.g. from Postman? If it's Azure it has hard timeout of 230 sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as by default `HttpClient` sets a [timeout of 100 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=xamarinandroid-7.1#Remarks).

---

**HttpClient Timeout**

You can adjust on your `HttpClient` and set a custom timeout duration. For example you can set an `InfiniteTimeSpan` to prevent timeouts from occuring.

`client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;`

---

**HttpClient Request Timeout**

You can additionally define a timeout per request using a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=xamarinandroid-7.1)

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan))
{
    await client.GetAsync(url, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```